# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'mentioned_user'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make something similar to the AFK command.

Code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.display_name.startswith("[AFK]"):
            await message.reply('Вау! Ты не в AFK? Что-же...')
            s = message.author.nick
            await message.author.edit(nick=f'{s}'.replace('[AFK]', ''))
            return
        elif message.mentioned_user.display_name.startswith("[AFK]") in message.content:
            await message.reply('Он в AFK!')
            return
        else:
            return
```

Error:

```py
 File "/home/runner/uuuu/cogs/events maybe.py", line 32, in on_message
    elif message.mentioned_user.display_name.startswith("[AFK]") in message.content:
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'mentioned_user
```

Comment: According to [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#message) there is no such field as `metioned_user`. You can use [`mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) and traverse all mentioned users.

Answer (score 1):

`mentioned_user` doesn't exist in `discord.Message`. I believe you were looking for [`.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) which returns a list of Members.

It does return a list so you will have to loop through it and then apply the code to each mention.